# React JSS (current) element selector - `&element`

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jss, makestyles

Is there a working equivalent for current element selector in React JSS styling syntax?

```
'&element': { margin: 0 }
```

**Use case**

I have this style for all `<Button>` components in my application.

```
'&:first-of-type': { marginLeft: 0 },
'&:last-of-type': { marginRight: 0 }
```

So if they appear in a row, the first one and the last one have appropriate margins.

However, sometimes I use

```
<Button component={Link} ../>
```

Which turns `Button` component into `a` element instead of `button`. This can mess up `:first-of-type` / `:last-of-type` selectors and cancel out margins for `a` element in between of the buttons.

My original intention was to set something like this, but this doesn't work.

```
'&button:first-of-type': { marginLeft: 0 },
'&button:last-of-type': { marginRight: 0 }
```

So far, I'm using the alternative

```
'&:first-of-type:not(a)': { marginLeft: 0 },
'&:last-of-type:not(a)': { marginRight: 0 }
```

Comment: As per @Oleg Isonen's answer below, give the parent element `padding-left` and `padding-right` instead of trying to give everything else `margin` or use the selector for children of the parent element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Button element shouldn't be responsible for the margin, because it breaks encapsulation, your component shouldn't take care of outer space, its parent should be.

Comment: just wanted to learn more about this and context behind it. Is this common practice for good UX? Where can I read more, what should I search for?